# What is the adjective to describe research approaches lacking theory proof?

Tags: single-word-requests, science, academia

When I write an academic paper and describe one of the previous researches, I found that the method is only based on the authors' own claims and lacks theory proof.

I am looking for a weak and negative/neutral adjective to describe their work (so that in the next part of paper we can highlight our contributions) .

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "lacking theoretical proof".  If you believe something may be true, that's a "theory".

Comment: Well, in everyday language, it’s a theory. In scientific language, “theory” denotes something very well supported indeed.

Comment: “Theoretical proof” is something of a self-contradiction, in a scientific context. Can you clarify how the article supports its conclusions, and what is missing?

Comment: You need to state what academic field you are in and give an example. There are list members that are experienced in scientific academic writing, and are willing to help, but at present your question is too unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You could say **speculative research**. It's not always necessarily negative, but it is if the author of the speculative research claims it proves anything. Other relevant words could be **rationalising, making assumptions**.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to describe their research *methods* — *untested*, *unvalidated*, *unsupported*, *unverified*, *unproven*, *speculative* — but extending any of them to their research *conclusions* would sound much more negative (or simply confusing). Since you want to say something "**weak** and negative/**neutral**", I'd suggest something like "using untested methods", rather than seeking a one-word adjective.

Comment: **Untested** seems like the best option, it's also used for drugs, an untested drug, meaning it has not been subject to (all) the appropriate scientific tests (yet) for it to be prescribed to (all) patients. [source: Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/untested)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

> **unsubstantiated** [adjective]
>
> Not supported or proven by evidence.
>
> *unsubstantiated claims*

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unsubstantiated)]

Answer (score 1):

Research based on **anecdotal** evidence:

anecdotal

ˌanɪkˈdəʊtl/

adjective

(of an account) not necessarily true or reliable, because based on personal accounts rather than facts or research.

"while there was much anecdotal evidence there was little hard fact"

Answer (score 1):

Approaches to science that assume the availability (and necessity) of theoretical proof are usually termed *positivist*. Alternate approaches in philosophy of science are termed generically *realist*, *relativist*, and *pragmatist*, to name the most important ones. The most neutral term you might use is *non-positivist*, which will not carry a pejorative tone at all, though you will be outing yourself as a positivist.

Answer (score 0):

"preliminary investigation" (or preliminary exploration) might be a way to avoid negativity.